# window.history.back()

Tags: javascript, dom, cache

Tenho uma página que possui um formulário com alguns dados e uma outra página posterior que possui um botão de voltar, a ideia é que quando o usuário utilize esse botão ele não perca os dados que foram digitados no formulário.

O problema é que os dados que o usuário digitou estão sendo mantidos porém os dados que foram carregados via "gatilho" do javascript voltam em branco, por exemplo.

Tenho um campo do tipo select que possui um `onchange`:

```
select name="cnpj" onchange="getnome(this.value);"
```

nessa função `getnome` eu busco o nome numa lista e faço a troca do valor através do comando abaixo

```
document.getElementsByName('nome')[0].value = aNomes.substr(posCnpj + 15, 30);
```

o nome é alterado com sucesso porém quando o usuário utiliza o botão voltar esse campo fica em branco, como se não tivesse sido preenchido.

isso só acontece com os campos que foram carregados no javascript seja com alteração via `.value` ou `setAttribute`, já tentei das duas formas

para voltar estou usando o `windows.history.back()`

alguém sabe como posso ajustar isso?

muito obrigado!

segue os códigos completos abaixo:

**index1.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index2.php">

        <select name="cnpj" onchange="getnome(this.value);"><option value="0"></option><option value="1">Teste1</option><option value="2">Teste2</option></select>
        <input type="text" name="nome" readonly="readonly" size="100">

        <button id="calcular" type="submit" size="5%" class="btn btn-success">Calcular orçamento</button>

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

**index2.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


        <button type="button" onclick="window.history.back()" class="btn btn-primary">Voltar</button>

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

**js.js**

```js
function getnome(valor) {

    document.getElementsByName('nome')[0].value = "teste";


}
```

Comment: Estou votando para fechar porque não consegui reproduzir o problema. Mesmo tentando alterar o valor e depois usar o "window.history.back()" todos os valores são mantidos. Não há código em sua pergunta que apresenta exatamente o problema.

Comment: Fala Inkeliz, obrigado pela interação, acabei de editar colocando os códigos.

Comment: Acabei de descobrir, o problema ocorre quando o campo está como readonly, sabe se tem alguma forma de deixar como leitura somente sem perder a informação na volta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aos que estiverem com o mesmo problema a solução foi retirar o `readonly` dos campos e fiz o bloqueio via css conforme abaixo:

```
input[name="nome"] {
  pointer-events:none;
  outline:none;
  background:#eee;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Dessa maneira voltando para a página anterior os valores foram mantidos.

Obrigado!